# Webpack React: Conditionally load json config files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have WebPack React project which I'm testing on my "**staging**" server.
Now its time to release it on "**production**" server.

I'm using **server.json** file which consists with server info such as api keys, api address, and so on.

What I want is to use different server.json for "production" and "staging".
And when I use production-server.json, there would be **no traces** of staging-server.json in my bundle.

```
src
- config
-- config.js
-- production-server.json
-- staging-server.json
```

maybe something like: yarn build-staging, yarn build-production

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use environment variables and webpack's [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/). Additionally, you can use [`node-config`](https://npmjs.com/package/config) to automatically load a json configuration file based on your `NODE_ENV`.

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "build:dev": "NODE_ENV=development start-something",
  "build": "NODE_ENV=production start-something"
}
```

**project config structure**

```
config
  default.json
    { "api": "https://api.mysite.com/v1" }
  staging.json
    { "api": "http://localhost:8000/v1" }
```

**webpack config**

```
// node-config will load your staging.json or default.json file here
// depending on what NODE_ENV is
const config = require('config');

plugins: [
  // inject window.CONFIG into your app
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    CONFIG: JSON.stringify(config)
  })
]
```

Then in your react code you will have access to environment-specific config

```
componentDidMount() {
  // in prod: https://api.mysite.com/v1/user/some-user-id
  // in staging: http://localhost:8000/v1/user/some-user-id
  return axios(`${CONFIG.api}/user/${this.props.userId}`).then(whatever...)
}
```

If you're on windows use [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) to set your environment variable.

Using `node-config` isn't the only way to do this, there are several, but I find it pretty easy, unless you're working with electron.

**edit**

Since `node-config` uses nodejs it is typically used in front end projects in conjunction with webpack. If you are unable to to integrate it with webpack you don't need to use `node-config` at all, I would do something like this:

**project structure**

```
config
  default.json
  development.json
  test.json
  index.js
src
  ...etc
```

**config files**

```
// default.json, typically used for production
{
  "api": "https://api.mysite.com/v1"
}

// development.json
{
  "api": "http://localhost:8000/v1"
}

// index.js
// get process.env via babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables
import production from './default.json';
import development from './development.json';
const { NODE_ENV: env } = process.env;

const config = {
  production,
  development
};

export default config[env];
```

Comment: But what about bundling? Webpack will bundle both config files?

Comment: @rendom no, webpack will only bundle what you give it. and `node-config` will only give you a single config object.

Comment: so this config files should be outside src directory, or it is doesn't matter?

Comment: what my question was. If I put server.json file inside src folder will webpack bundle it too? In your example you used different folder for config storing

Comment: @rendom just get rid of `server.json`. it's better to organize config files by env name.

Comment: Unfortunately this method is not working with react-native(I know this was not in original question). How do you think, Is It possible to use this with react native metro bundler?